# static asserting lambda that captures

Tags: c++, c++17

I am learning parallel programming and meta-programming at the moment and I have struggle making compile time check for lambda that captures variable.

Let us say that we have code like this one:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    auto non_capture = [](){
        std::cout<<"this lambda is not capturing!"<<std::endl;
    };

    auto capture = [&](){
        std::cout<<"this lambda is capturing"<<std::endl;
    };

    //value is true for this one
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<decltype(non_capture), std::function<void()>>::value, "message1");

    //i need help for this
    static_assert(is_lambda_that_captures<decltype(capture)>::value, "this is some error message");
}
```

I need help to define **is_lambda_that_captures** type trait so I can pass the second static assert. How can I do it?

Having a solution for the latest standard is more than welcome(current latest is c++17) :)

Comment: Do I get it right, You want to have different traits for capturing and non-capturing lambda? I don't think it's possible

Comment: Is it important that it checks whether the type is actually a lambda or not?

Comment: @bartop I don't think it is possible to make type trait that works with both capturing and non-capturing lambdas at the same time, if there is one that I am not aware of I will.certainly use one.

Comment: @Rakete1111 For non-capture lambda I solved by checking if it is convertible to function pointer. Yes non-capture lambdas can be converted to function pointer. I am not aware into what capturing lambdas are convertible. I just need to pass the assert without changing the signature of that lambda.

Comment: It's ease in cpp17 to do it for both. I'll give an answer in a second

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want ... any type trait that returns true? Like `template <typename T> struct trait : std::true_type { };`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For C++17 You can leverage the latest trait: [`std::is_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable). It should work fine for both capturing and non-capturing lambda:

```
static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<decltype(noncapture)>,"Error?!");
static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<decltype(capture)>,"Error?!");
```

Of course it will work also for function pointers, `std::function` and all objects with `operator()` accessible. If You want to detect only lambdas (for which I don't see much use), You will need more trait magic.

Comment: @Rakete1111 The author of question said: " I don't think it is possible to make type trait that works with both capturing and non-capturing lambdas at the same time, if there is one that I am not aware of I will.certainly use one." in one of comments, so I gave an example.

Comment: Let's allow people and author of question decide if my answer is useful ;)

Comment: I do not know how I missed this trait from cppreference. Thank you!

Comment: This trait is useful, but you didn't answer question asked in title - how to distinguish lambda that captures from free one. Not sure why this is an accepted answer. @NikolaLozanovski

Answer (score 5):

Here's my solution. It relies on two principles:

1. non-capuring lambdas are convertible to function pointers.
2. All lambdas are convertible to std::function.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, class Ret, class...Args>
struct is_non_capture_lambda : std::is_convertible<T, Ret (*)(Args...)>
{

};

template<class T, class Ret, class...Args>
struct is_capture_lambda
{
    static constexpr auto convertible = std::is_convertible<T, std::function<Ret(Args...)>>::value;
    using type = bool;
    static constexpr auto value = convertible && !is_non_capture_lambda<T, Ret, Args...>::value;


};

int main(){

    auto non_capture = [](){
        std::cout<<"this lambda is not capturing!"<<std::endl;
    };

    auto capture = [&](){
        std::cout<<"this lambda is capturing"<<std::endl;
    };

    //value is true for this one
    static_assert(is_non_capture_lambda<decltype(non_capture), void>::value, "message1");

    //i need help for this
    static_assert(is_capture_lambda<decltype(capture), void>::value, "this is some error message");
}
```

Comment: Note that this will treat a pure function pointer as a non-capturing lambda (although I'm not sure why one would care about the difference), and will treat an appropriate `std::function` as a capturing lambda (again, not sure why one would care).

Comment: @MartinBonner yes it occurred to me to code in some detection of that, and I like you realised that there is (almost) no semantic difference in the 2 cases. I think we'd need to know more about the motivation.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, note that

```
static_assert(
    std::is_convertible<decltype(capture), std::function<void()>>::value, 
    "msg");
```

would also pass.  *Any* lambda can be converted into a `std::function` of the appropriate type.  The difference between a capturing lambda and a non-capturing lambda is that a non-capturing lambda can be converted into a pointer to function.  So:

```
 static_assert(
     std::is_convertible<decltype(non_capture), void (*)()>>::value, 
     "msg");
```

will pass, but

```
 static_assert(
     std::is_convertible<decltype(capture), void (*)()>>::value, 
     "msg");
```

will fail.  You can distinguish between a non-capturing lambda and an actual function pointer with `std::is_class` (but I can't think why you would want to).

Comment: This fails for generic lambdas.

Comment: @Rakete Bother!

Comment: I tried is_convertible with std::function but maybe I messed something on my first try., on my second it worked. This is one of the solution I would need. Thank you!